# strange form submit url encoding issue

Tags: php, http, url

I am having a strange issue. Please check this url:

http://www.goodtherapy.org/newsearch/search.html?search[zipcode]=R3T+2H5+&search[miles]=25

You will see the request uri is same as the url.

But try here:
http://www.goodtherapy.org/

in the search form in the middle, enter text "R3T 2H5" (just to create the same url above) and click "search" button. You will see request uri is got url encoded.

I am using this php code to show the uri:

```
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];exit;
```

why is this? How to get rid of it please?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code. I got this `/newsearch/search.html?search%5Bzipcode%5D=mumbai&search%5Bmiles%5D=25&TOS+agreement=Search`

Comment: I thought that it's browser specific. Which means some browsers show you the url encoded and the others don't.

Comment: I get this in chrome: `/newsearch/search.html?search%5Bzipcode%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmislav%2Fwill_paginate%2Fwiki%2FBackwards-incompatibility&search%5Bmiles%5D=25&TOS+agreement=Search`

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, I think you are talking about the second attempt on home page by using search form, right? That is the problem I am having. I need to be it exactly same as the first url on browser.

Comment: Why are you complicating things, just add [**url_decode()**](http://php.net/url-decode) and you're done, whether it's url encoded or not.

Comment: @HamZa , But It used to work fine before. May be we need to tell some encoding format etc in html?

Comment: @Rana `It did work fine before` -> this isn't a good sign. This means something has changed. Software update ? Code modification ? Other browser you're using ? Or you just didn't spot it before ? What I mean don't bother too much, and wrap your output like this `echo urldecode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);exit;`. Which will make it work for everyone. (btw I don't get `+` in the output ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually whenever you use html forms, the post url always get encoded just because to assure the validity of the url , as url support ascii characters...

the string you are pasting it directly in url, is not going through any script or form, it does not change, and that is valid way to do that.

So try to use some decodeing way..

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by changing the search[zipcode] to search_zipcode '[]'  returns %5 in url.